# How to extract Sha256 Cert Fingerprint for Branch.io

Tags: android, deep-linking, twitter-fabric, branch.io, deeplink

I am trying to integrate deep linking with branch.io. But in order to do this. I need to extract the SHA256 Cert Fingerprints to put them in my branch.io dashboard. How Do I do this? what is my certificate?
They have too little data on how this is done.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Execute this command:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore
```

Source: https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/index.html#web-assoc

Comment: Thanks, wasn't sure if the "Cert" is the keystore or not

Comment: Still ain't sure, cause Branch doesn't work as it should... But atleast I tried :(

Comment: The SHA256 certificate will be listed if you execute this command (replace the my-release-key.keystore with the actual production keystore)

Comment: Yes. I know, I did it, I extracted the key, thanks. I can set this as answered. But Branch still doesn't work for me, but hey, back to the drawing board

Comment: saved my MBP , i was about to bang it on the wall.

Answer (score 22):

Check out below image,
where you can see `SHA256` key available on play store after live your app.

[image]

Answer (score 11):

The SHA265 fingerprint is related to your app’s signing certificate. `keytool -list -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore` is the right command to generate it, but there are additional steps you need to take before everything will work as expected. You can find a full walkthrough of how to configure this in the [Branch Android App Links guide](https://help.branch.io/using-branch/docs/android-app-links).

Comment: That link is for iOS. Here's the link to the Android Branch App Links: https://docs.branch.io/pages/deep-linking/android-app-links/

Answer (score 7):

Small update to [Prashant Avrind's excellent pictorial answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58668662/4520965).

After publishing with Google App Signing enabled the SHA256 key is now available under Setup > App Integrity.
[image: SHA256]

Comment: Thank you, as Google Play Console's UI has updated this helped me out!